# Using keystores with Websphere and WSS4j

Tags: java, web-applications, keystore, wss4j

I am implementing a solution that includes using WSS4j for *signature validation* and *decryption*.There will be two key stores, one for each of these purposes.This is being done in a servlet webapp. For testing I am putting the key store/crypto properties files in the EAR but we need a more long term solution.

Is there a way to store the key store on Websphere, perhaps through a JNDI that could be referenced by a crypto object for WSS4J? Our administrator is trying to avoid placing the keystore straight on the file system.

Comment: Why exactly is your administrator trying to avoid placing the keystore straight on the file system?

Comment: He wants to use websphere functionality like a JNDI because its easier to administer I believe.